# How do I make calls to operating system functions in the language of my choice?

Tags: system-calls

This is a question that I have long been wanting answered.

Major operating systems such as Windows and Mac OS X generally only "support" one or a few languages (i.e. C++, C#, VB for Windows, Objective-C for Mac OS X).

Using the Go language as an example, it's obviously possible to interact with the operating system and make calls to these functions without using the "supported" languages.

How is this possible?

What does a developer need to know in order to call these system functions using the language of his choice?

**I'm looking for how these calls are represented in code - and how they are then used upon execution.**

I expect that there isn't one answer that fits every language-system combination... but a few different examples would be helpful.

Comment: It will be very dependant on the language. Using your Go example (in which I should emphasize I have no experience, this is based on a quick Google search), you could use the [syscall](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) or [os](http://golang.org/pkg/os/) package.

Comment: One needs to know how to Google. Other than that, I doubt there's a generic answer. So the question is likely ["not constructive"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ABI ([Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) defines how to make a call to the operating system.  To be able to make those calls requires the particular programming language implementation to generate code conforming to that ABI.

Making OS calls in C is well-supported, and many interpreted languages (e.g., perl, python, tcl) are implemented in C, so they are in essence making the calls via C.

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer will lead me in the direction I want.